# solaris 10 + install solaris from cdrom + read disk error

Tags: solaris, boot, opensolaris, solaris-10

I want to install solaris 10 on my netra machine - T5220

```
{0} OK boot cdrom - install
```

but I get the errors below - please advice what could be the problem ?

```
can't read disk label
can't open disk label package
ERROR boot read failed
```

Comment: Is the CD-ROM drive OK? Is the installation disc OK?

Comment: thx I replaced the CD and now I can boot from the CD-ROM thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your installation CD and/or CD-ROM drive is faulty. Replace CD, drive or both of them. Then retry.